# NodeJS: Sending a method to client (socket.io)

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I was testing with NodeJS and Socket.io for a chat. Now I have a really nice idea for sending errors to the client, like your username is already taken etc.

**Server:**

```
...
} else if(searchUser(data.userName)) {
    socket.emit('errorCode', {
        sendError: function() {
            alert("Username already taken!!");
        }
    });
} else {
...
```

**Client:**

```
/* Error Handler */
socket.on('errorCode', function(data) {
    data.sendError();
});
```

But this is not working. I think it should be possible, maybe I`m doing something wrong. I also want to send jQuery instructions over socket.io.

Have anyone a idea how to get this to work?

Comment: Emit the message and alert from the client.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Ben Fortune I have this idea:

**Server**

```
sendError: 'alert("Username already taken")'
```

**Client**

```
eval(data.sendError);
```